# Retrieving Sub-XML Elements to display a Pie Chart

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, pie-chart

I have designed an application that will load the information from an XML File to a Pie Chart.

First my XML looked like this

```
<books>
   <stock>

    <booktype>Novels</booktype>
    <amountofbooks>100</amountofbooks>

   </stock>
</books>
```

And my AS code looked like

```
[Bindable]
private var bookStock:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

var myPieSeries:PieSeries = new PieSeries();
myPieSeries.nameField = "booktype";
myPieSeries.field = "amountofbooks";
```

in the `result` event I do this

```
bookStock = evt.result.books.stock;
```

Now this works perfectly and I can see the generated Pie Chart.

But now let's say that I changed the XML in the following manner.

```
<books>
   <stock>
        <bookinfo>
            <booktype>Fiction</booktype>
            <amountofbooks>150</amountofbooks>
        </bookinfo>     
    </stock>

   <stock>
        <bookinfo>
          <booktype>Novels</booktype>
          <amountofbooks>100</amountofbooks>
        </bookinfo> 
   </stock>

</books>
```

in the results event how do I access it?

`bookStock = evt.result.books.stock.bookinfo;`

doesn't work. I get a "Error: Unknown Property: 'bookinfo'."

When I analysed the bookStock object I get this.

[image: Debug Image]

How do I access the XML element now? Does anything needs to be changed here?

```
myPieSeries.nameField = "booktype";
myPieSeries.field = "amountofbooks";
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the project that I am working with.

http://min.us/mvkoXsU

Comment: Could you put the full code up (or a link to it) so we could run it ourselves? I would suggest reading to an XMLList first (debug that to make sure its correct), then convert that to an array if you like. var _xmlList:XMLList = evt.result.books.stock;

Comment: @Brian: I updated the answer with a link to the project

Comment: I could finally solve the problem by using e4x as the result type and setting `bookStock = evt.result..bookinfo;`

Comment: @Brian: Thanx! :) It's called the "descendant accessor"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually xml.books.stock.bookinfo will get you an XMLList of XML nodes and I think your error comes either from assigning that XMLList to the ArrayCollection instance, or by treating every item of that XMLList as an Array, when in fact they are XML nodes.

I've never worked with ArrayCollection, but I think you'll need to traverse (for loop) your XMLList and put together the ArrayCollection manually.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have right now, is that you are treating an XMLList like XML.

```
// this works because there is only one XML node for each item in the chain
bookStock = evt.result.books.stock;

// how does this work?
bookStock = evt.result.books.stock.bookinfo;

// there are multiple stock nodes inside of "books"
bookStock = evt.result.books.stock[0].bookinfo;

trace(bookStock);//should trace the bookinfo from the first element
```

Give that a try.

Comment: ok, Now I understand :) But how do I get all the stock[].bookinfo results to the Array?

Comment: I get a Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.utils::ObjectProxy@54ac509 to mx.collections.ArrayCollection error when I try this.

Comment: Its not going to be an Array, you'll get an XML object back (wrapped in an ObjectProxy). Why would you want the bookInfo node to return an array? What would the array contain, something like this ['Fiction', '150']?

Comment: I need an Array because I need to use it to generate a Pie Chart. Please bare with as I am a beginner to AS and Flex.